# User touch quickly on MediaController. Bug only happens on Nexus 4.

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, mediacontroller, android-videoview

In my activity I have got a VideoView which should show a MediaController on touch. If the user touches quickly on Controller while VideoView is not following, after that user presses back button, then my app will be stuck.

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_play_video_fullscreen);
videoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.video_view);

urlString = getIntent().getStringExtra(EXTRA_URL);
videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(urlString));
videoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // video ready to play - hide progress bar
        ProgressBar pb = (ProgressBar)findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);
        pb.setVisibility(ProgressBar.INVISIBLE);
    }
});

videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        // video finished - terminate this activity
        AxUtils.axLog(AxUtils.eDbgLogError, AxUtils.eDbgLogGroupDialer, String.format("PlayVideoFullsreenActivity.videoView.onCompletion(): Fullscreen video playback completed.\n"));
        finish();
    }
});

// install our own error handler
videoView.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
        AxUtils.axLog(AxUtils.eDbgLogError, AxUtils.eDbgLogGroupDialer, String.format("PlayVideoFullsreenActivity.videoView.onError(): Playback failed. what=%d(%s) extra=%d(%s)\n", 
                what, what_toString(what), extra, extra_toString(extra)));
        String reason;
        if (what == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED) {
            reason = "Server connection lost.";
        }
        else {
            reason = extra_toString(extra);
        }
        String message = String.format("Playback Failed. %s", reason);
        Toast.makeText(PlayVideoFullscreenActivity.this.getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        finish();
        return true;
    }
});

// add playback controls
mediaController = new MediaController(this);
mediaController.setAnchorView(videoView.getRootView());
videoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
```

Comment: Please post some code

Comment: @Niko I was edit my post

Comment: How does the app get stuck?

Comment: when user scroll mediacontroller quickly, after that press back button then app stuck user cannot interactive

Comment: Just free all the resources while onDestroy called.

Comment: Add some part of your log, show something irregular which need to mention?

Comment: Probably the UI gets freeze. Do the network connectivity on different thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your preparedListeners, disable and enable your media controllers. It should solve your issue.

Good luck.